# В какой форме отправлять выполненное задание?

Tags: python

Прислали задание, просят написать программу на python, писал 2 недели, меня глюкануло по русски говоря и у меня возник вопрос, а что они от меня хотят, чтобы я им просто прислал сиходный код (файл.py) что ли? Или обернул во что то? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

В случае с питоном скорее всего как раз и нужен исходный код + инструкция, как запускать. Но есть такие варианты:

- это тестовое задание. Тогда скорее всего они знают, что делать
- это программа для какого-то человека, тогда, скорее всего нужно будет рассказать, как установить питон и пользоваться программой.